# Magento 1.9 getCustomer Telephone in PDF Print-outs

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer, pdf

Hi I have some custom code to display PDF Print-out, everything work fine except that customer telephone number, I have this code in php to define that variables:

```
      $processor->setVariables(
            array(
                'order'           => $order,
                'sales_object'    => $order,
                'billing_address' => $pdf->PrepareCustomerAddress($orderHelper, $order, 'billing'),
                'shipping_address'=> $pdf->PrepareCustomerAddress($orderHelper, $order, 'shipping'),
                'payment'         => $pdf->PreparePayment($orderHelper, $order, $order),
                'shipping'        => nl2br($pdf->PrepareShipping($orderHelper, $order, $order))
            )
        );
```

and I try to use in phtml file like this:

```
{{htmlescape var=$billing_address.getTelephone()}}
```

but the field Phone is blank, if I use only `{{htmlescape var=$billing_address}}` display the entire customer address including phone number too.

How I can get only the Customer Telephone number?

**THIS IS THE PHTML CODE:**

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td height="50"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="81%" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle"><font size="120px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{var sales_object.increment_id}}</font></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><div align="center">REGISTRATION NUMBER</div></td>
      <td align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><div align="center">CONTACT INFORMATION</div></td>
    <td width="19%" align="center" valign="top"><font size="32px">{{var sales_object.increment_id}}</font></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td height="200px"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">FIRST NAME:</td>
      <td align="center">LAST NAME:</td>
      <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">{{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerFirstname()}}</td>
      <td align="center">{{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerLastname()}}</td>
      <td align="left"><font size="-2"></font></td>
      <td align="center" valign="top"><font face="microgme_1" size="9px">{{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerFirstname()}}</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="center" height="20px"><div align="left">EMAIL: {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerEmail()}}</div></td>
      <td align="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="center" height="20px"><div align="left">PHONE: {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerTelephone()}} </div></td>
      <td align="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="center"></td>
      <td align="center"><font face="microgme_1" size="9px">{{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerLastname()}}</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    <td height="25px"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
      <td align="center" ><font face="microgme_1" size="9px"><b>{{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerEmail()}}</b></font></td>
    </tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you share your all code in question?

Comment: can you tell me please what code you need? is an entire extension with a lot of code

Comment: are you trying code {{htmlescape var=$billing_address.getTelephone()}} in which file? can you pls share this file code?

Comment: please take a look I edit my post and I add this code

Comment: try this {{htmlescape var=$order.getBillingAddress()->getTelephone()}}. Not sure it working or not

Comment: no, still blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bellow code

php code define variables:

```
$processor->setVariables(
        array(
            'order'               => $order,
            'sales_object'        => $order,
            'billing_address'     => $pdf->PrepareCustomerAddress($orderHelper, $order, 'billing'),
            'shipping_address'    => $pdf->PrepareCustomerAddress($orderHelper, $order, 'shipping'),
            'payment'             => $pdf->PreparePayment($orderHelper, $order, $order),
            'shipping'           => nl2br($pdf->PrepareShipping($orderHelper, $order, $order)),
            'customer_telephone'  => $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone(),
        )
    );
```

In phtm file use below code:

```
PHONE: {{htmlescape var=$customer_telephone}}
```

Comment: thank you, I don't know why but is still blank

Comment: aaa is okay now, in your code was space between var = $custome.... is okay now, thank you so much for your help

Comment: Updated ans pls check now